# GCD crashes in iOS5

Tags: objective-c, ios, grand-central-dispatch

I am developing a Static library. 
And i am using reverse Auth in the library using source code from [here](https://github.com/seancook/TWReverseAuthExample).
In this library, the following crashes in iOS5, but works fine in iOS6.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)
```

If we change the line as follows, it works fine in all OS versions.

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()
```

Will the change work in all circumstances or will it create any problem?
Please advice, Thank you.

Comment: What error do you get? crash log?

Comment: Thank you for the reply @mprivat. It throws "objc_msgSend" in iOS 5 simulator, i do not have iOS 5 device, but it works fine in iOS 6 device.

Comment: I had the same issue, but was being dumb.  I had set the Deployment Target of my app as 6.0.  Changing this back down to 5.0 allowed me to keep the same "dispatch_async" line of code, and worked on both OSs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to tell without being able to see your code, but this sounds like you are sending a message without your GCD block to an object created before the block and that is no longer alive at the time the block executes. I suggest setting as a property to retain it so ARC doesn't get it collected.

The discrepancy between iOS versions could be due to differences between the simulator and the device (you said you run the iOS 6 version on the device, and 5 on the simulator).